# LeetCode: Trie Tree implementation, Search, Insert, startWith C#

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, trie

https://leetcode.com/problems/implement-trie-prefix-tree/

Please comment about performance and style.

> Implement a trie with insert, search, and startsWith methods.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> Trie trie = new Trie();
>
> trie.insert("apple");
> trie.search("apple");   // returns true
> trie.search("app");     // returns false
> trie.startsWith("app"); // returns true
> trie.insert("app");   
> trie.search("app");     // returns true
> ```
>
> Note:
>
> You may assume that all inputs are consist of lowercase letters a-z.
>   All inputs are guaranteed to be non-empty strings.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace TrieQuestions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://leetcode.com/problems/implement-trie-prefix-tree/
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class TrieTreeImplementation
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TrieInsertTest()
        {
            Trie trie = new Trie();
            trie.Insert("cat");
            Assert.IsTrue(trie.Search("cat"));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TriePrefixSearchTest()
        {
            Trie trie = new Trie();
            trie.Insert("cats");
            Assert.IsTrue(trie.StartsWith("cat"));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void OneLetterEdgeCaseTest()
        {
            Trie trie = new Trie();
            trie.Insert("a");
            Assert.IsTrue(trie.Search("a"));
            Assert.IsTrue(trie.StartsWith("a"));
        }
    }

    public class Trie
    {
        public TrieNode Head { get; set; }

        /** Initialize your data structure here. */
        public Trie()
        {
            Head = new TrieNode();
        }

        /** Inserts a word into the trie. */
        public void Insert(string word)
        {
            var current = Head;
            for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!current.Edges.ContainsKey(word[i]))
                {
                    current.Edges.Add(word[i], new TrieNode());
                }
                current = current.Edges[word[i]];
            }
            current.IsTerminal = true;
        }

        /** Returns if the word is in the trie. */
        public bool Search(string word)
        {
            var current = Head;
            for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!current.Edges.ContainsKey(word[i]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                current = current.Edges[word[i]];
            }
            return current.IsTerminal == true;
        }

        /** Returns if there is any word in the trie that starts with the given prefix. */
        public bool StartsWith(string prefix)
        {
            var current = Head;
            for (int i = 0; i < prefix.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!current.Edges.ContainsKey(prefix[i]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                current = current.Edges[prefix[i]];
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class TrieNode
    {
        public Dictionary<char, TrieNode> Edges { get; set; }
        public bool IsTerminal { get; set; }
        public TrieNode()
        {
            Edges = new Dictionary<char, TrieNode>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @wolfy no you can't. Why is it better? Maybe I can create a singleton or something close to it.

Comment: @Wolfy: C# is a managed language, so I'm not sure what you're getting at?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet ahh okay then nevermind, sorry I never used C# before...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In terms of data structures and algorithms this all looks pretty straightforward - not much to say about that.

#### Performance

- `Edges.ContainsKey` and `Edges[...]` each perform a lookup. `Edges.TryGetValue` lets you achieve the same with just a single lookup.

#### Design

- I see no reason why `Trie.Head` should be public, and certainly not why it should have a public setter. That's poor encapsulation. Likewise, `TrieNode.Edges` should be get-only: you don't want outside code to be able to do `Edges = null;`.
- `Search` and `StartsWith` do exactly the same thing, except for the final check. I'd move the duplicate code to a `TrieNode FindNode(string prefix)` helper method.
- `TrieNode` is only used internally within `Trie`, so it makes sense to make it a private inner class.

#### Other notes

- You can remove `Trie`'s constructor if you initialize `Head` directly: `TrieNode Head { get; } = new TrieNode();`. The same goes for `TrieNode` and `Edges`.
- I'd replace those `for` loops with `foreach` loops, for clarity's sake.
- Comparing a boolean against `true` is unnecessary. Just do `return current.IsTerminal;`
- I'd replace those default LeetCode comments with C#-specific xml comments.